# F# ignores CallingConvention set in DllImport attribute?

Tags: compiler-construction, f#

While trying to call function with following signature (compiled by MSVC++):

```
BOOL CreateJunctionPoint(LPCTSTR szMountDir, LPCTSTR szDestDir);
```

and described in F# as

```
[<DllImport("FSLinks.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)>]
extern int CreateJunctionPoint(string source, string target)
```

I get stack imbalance.

The same function called from C# works perfectly.

After changing calling convention to stdcall in C++:

```
 BOOL  __stdcall CreateJunctionPoint(LPCTSTR szMountDir, LPCTSTR szDestDir);
```

F# program begin working normally (though still having CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl set)
Seems like obvious compiler bug to me.

Both compilers are from Visual Studio 2010 (Microsoft (R) F# 2.0 Compiler build 4.0.30319.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a known bug.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/612713/f-ignores-callingconvention-for-dllimport

Comment: It seems that Microsoft support at connect were not able to reproduce the bug. And this means that it won't be fixed, am I right?

Comment: @Alexander According to the update from 10/13/2010, they were able to reproduce it. Aside, Brian is from the F# team, so if he says it is a known bug, that's a good sign :-)

Comment: This was fixed in VS 2010 SP 1. And, if I recall correctly, the equivalent non-VS binary release.